# SSH to Azure: Connection reset by peer

Tags: azure, ssh, virtual-machine, openssh

I'm trying to SSH into a VM in Azure but any I try I get the following error:

```
ssh -i keytest.pem -vvv azureuser@x.x.x.x
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname x.x.x.x is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file keytest.pem type -1
debug1: identity file keytest.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

This isn't present for others trying to access the VM's, it is present in both WSL and PowerShell.
I am accessing this via a VPN.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

•   Please follow the below steps to resolve your issue while doing SSH to the VM in Azure through WSL and powershell by trying to connect it via VPN: -

a)  Please check whether your **IP is not blacklisted by the server** and **whitelist it** so that you are able to SSH to the Azure VM. To do this, please edit the **‘etc/hosts.allow’** file by executing the command – **sudo nano /etc/hosts.allow** and updating the value of **ALL** key to **ALL** like **ALL : ALL**. Thus, it will allow all the IP addresses to connect to the Azure VM via SSH over the VPN. Also, it might be that the SSH port is blocked over the VPN, if yes then check accordingly.

b)  Similarly, check the **etc/hosts.deny** file for any deny and allow lists that it maintains. Try to **reboot the Azure VM** to which you want to connect through SSH.

c)  It might also be that the **SSH daemon is not responding** on the Azure VM side and you should try **reconnecting via IP-KVM** and **restart the SSHD service** by executing the below command – **sudo systemctl restart sshd && systemctl status sshd**. Then further, execute the below commands to ensure that the SSHD folder has requisite permissions: -

```
   sudo mkdir /var/run/sshd
   sudo chmod 755 -R /var/run/sshd
   sudo service ssh restart ’
```

By following the above steps, most probably you should be able to overcome the issue to connect to the Azure VM over SSH.